# Create page break for entire frame without breaking the text flow

Tags: page-breaking, boxes, framed

I'm including a large, one page box using `framed` package, with simplest example being:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \begin{document}
        Some text        
        \begin{framed}
        A lot of text for entire page box.
        \end{framed}
        Some more text
    \end{document}
```

By default, it brakes this large box into two boxes distributed across two pages, with the flow of all text surrounding it. But I want to keep the box intact, unbroken. However, when I add `\pagebreak` or `\clearpage` before `\begin{framed}`, it moves the entire box to new page, but creates a gap in previous page. The question is: how to put the box in the next page without braking it AND without creating gaps in text surrounding the box?

Comment: What is the question? How not to break the box? or how to put the box in next page without gaps?

Comment: @HarishKumar I edited the question to clarify

Comment: I have added an answer. Is it what you want?

Comment: You could place the `framed` environment inside a float like `figure` and use the `[t]` (top) position. When used without `\caption` it does not effect the numbering of real floats. However, if you have not yet placed floats beforehand it will mess with the positioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `afterpage`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1-3]
    \afterpage{%
    \begin{framed}
    \kant[1-3]
    \end{framed}
    }
    \kant[1-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]